# Bootstrap tooltip not showing in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I've got a rather weird scenario going on here. I am trying to add tooltips to an existing ASP.Net MVC application in which I'm upgrading Bootstrap to 4.6.2. The upgrade was very smooth with no complications; I just want to replace the default display of titles with the nicer looking tooltips, but for some reason they're not appearing. I tried to simplify things by creating a new view to isolate the problem, and still no tooltip. I tried again with completely new solution, and wouldn't you know it, it works! So my question isn't "how do I create tooltips", but "how can I debug what's going on in the failing project?"

Here's what I've discovered so far. I believe you can see everything that's relevant in this screenshot of the nearly-empty view. All the included script files are there in the right order, my script is there, initializing the tooltip, and there are no messages in the console. When I hover over the link, a new `<div>` element is added to the DOM. In DevTools, I use the arrows to expand the tree, showing everything in the tooltip. The `.fade:not(.show)` CSS selector is the reason I don't see it. In the working solution, the `show` class is properly added to the tooltip's `<div>`.

So, could there be some setting in the existing application preventing the addition of the `show` class? Is something failing in the tooltip code,causing it to never add the `show` class without reporting errors? How should I continue debugging this? I tried stepping through the `bootstap.js` file, but being a JS noob, I'm getting a little lost. The screenshot is from Chrome, but I see the same behavior in Firefox.

[image: Screenshot of invisible tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be one of those embarrassing oversights. My `BundleConfig.cs` file was still pointing to old Javascript files that were still hanging around after the upgrade. I should have seen it in the version numbers in the `<script>` tags.